# Converting an abnormal JSON string to List<class>

Tags: c#, json, list

I came a cross a web service from another company that returns an abnormal JSON string.

This is what the JSON look like:

```
["TERMINAL_NO","METER_NO","RAMZE_RAYANEH_SHENASE_GHABZ","PARVANDEH_ESHTERAK","POWER_UTILITY","CT_RATIO","PT_RATIO","NAME_","PART","CUSTOMER_ID","X_POS","Y_POS","DATE_NUM","HOUR_NUM","MONTH_","DAY_","YEAR_","DAY_WEEK","MONTH_DAY","DATE_HOUR","ACTIVE_ENERGY_PLUS_TOTAL","ACTIVE_ENERGY_PLUS_TARIF_1","ACTIVE_ENERGY_PLUS_TARIF_2","ACTIVE_ENERGY_PLUS_TARIF_3","ACTIVE_ENERGY_PLUS_TARIF_4","ACTIVE_ENERGY_MINUS_TOTAL","ACTIVE_ENERGY_MINUS_TARIF_1","ACTIVE_ENERGY_MINUS_TARIF_2","ACTIVE_ENERGY_MINUS_TARIF_3","ACTIVE_ENERGY_MINUS_TARIF_4","REACTIVE_ENERGY_PLUS_TOTAL","REACTIVE_ENERGY_PLUS_TARIF_1","REACTIVE_ENERGY_PLUS_TARIF_2","REACTIVE_ENERGY_PLUS_TARIF_3","REACTIVE_ENERGY_PLUS_TARIF_4","REACTIVE_ENERGY_MINUS_TOTAL","REACTIVE_ENERGY_MINUS_TARIF_1","REACTIVE_ENERGY_MINUS_TARIF_2","REACTIVE_ENERGY_MINUS_TARIF_3","REACTIVE_ENERGY_MINUS_TARIF_4","VOLTAGE_PHASE_A","VOLTAGE_PHASE_B","VOLTAGE_PHASE_C","CURRENT_PHASE_A","CURRENT_PHASE_B","CURRENT_PHASE_C","POWER_ACTIV_AVG","POWER_ACTIV_MIN","POWER_ACTIV_MAX","POWER_REACT_AVG","POWER_REACT_MIN","POWER_REACT_MAX","POWER_FACTOR_PHASE_A","POWER_FACTOR_PHASE_B","POWER_FACTOR_PHASE_C","READ_FLAG"],
["039530059094","039530059094","8448430104225","2420815","\u06a9\u0646\u062a\u0648\u0631\u0647\u0627\u06cc \u062f\u06cc\u0645\u0627\u0646\u062f\u06cc \u0627\u0633\u062a\u0627\u0646 \u062a\u0647\u0631\u0627\u0646","100\/5","1\/1","Ali Falahi","\u06af\u0644\u0633\u062a\u0627\u0646","2420815",null,null,"13980607","0","06","07","1398","\u067e\u0646\u062c \u0634\u0646\u0628\u0647","0607","0607.0",null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,"OFFLINE"],
["039530059094","039530059094","8448430104225","2420815","\u06a9\u0646\u062a\u0648\u0631\u0647\u0627\u06cc \u062f\u06cc\u0645\u0627\u0646\u062f\u06cc \u0627\u0633\u062a\u0627\u0646 \u062a\u0647\u0631\u0627\u0646","100\/5","1\/1","Ali Falahi","\u06af\u0644\u0633\u062a\u0627\u0646","2420815",null,null,"13980607","1","06","07","1398","\u067e\u0646\u062c \u0634\u0646\u0628\u0647","0607","0607.1",null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,"OFFLINE"]
```

The first row of data is the name of the columns and the rest is the data.
Since I can't tell them to change their data format, how can I convert this to list of class or anything like list of key-value pair with relative columns?

Comment: You might as well use a csv, this JSON is not that useful and you won't be able to parse it into a useful class (apart from a list of objects).

Comment: This is certainly not valid JSON.  As @Hytam suggests I would treat this as CSV using a helper class such as CsvHelper, but you will first need to read the string and remove the extra [ ] characters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on how you plan to use the data. My guess is that you need to be able to pair the elements of the first row with the data in the 1st thru nth rows. So perhaps the desired output is a list of dictionaries.

If that is the case, I suggest you parse it as JSON (not as a CSV-- the escaping rules are different) then map the fields into the data structure you need. For example:

```
var array = JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType("[" + input + "]" , (string[][])null);
Console.WriteLine("There were {0} rows with {1} columns", array.Length, array[0].Length);
var list = new List<Dictionary<string,string>>();
for (var i = 1; i<= array.GetUpperBound(0); i++)
{
    var dictionary = array[0]
        .Zip(array[i], (l,r) => new KeyValuePair<string,string>(l,r))
        .ToDictionary( pair => pair.Key, pair => pair.Value);
    list.Add(dictionary);
}

Console.WriteLine("We now have a list of {0} rows", list.Count);

for (int i=0; i<list.Count; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine("\r\nHere is row {0}\r\n", i);
    var dictionary = list[i];
    foreach (var key in dictionary.Keys)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} = {1}", key, dictionary[key]);
    }
}
```

Output looks like this:

```
There were 3 rows with 56 columns
We now have a list of 2 rows

Here is row 0

TERMINAL_NO = 039530059094
METER_NO = 039530059094
RAMZE_RAYANEH_SHENASE_GHABZ = 8448430104225
PARVANDEH_ESHTERAK = 2420815
POWER_UTILITY = ???????? ??????? ????? ?????
CT_RATIO = 100/5
PT_RATIO = 1/1
NAME_ = Ali Falahi
PART = ??????
CUSTOMER_ID = 2420815
X_POS = 
Y_POS = 
DATE_NUM = 13980607
HOUR_NUM = 0
MONTH_ = 06
DAY_ = 07
YEAR_ = 1398
DAY_WEEK = ??? ????
MONTH_DAY = 0607
DATE_HOUR = 0607.0
ACTIVE_ENERGY_PLUS_TOTAL = 
ACTIVE_ENERGY_PLUS_TARIF_1 = 
ACTIVE_ENERGY_PLUS_TARIF_2 = 
ACTIVE_ENERGY_PLUS_TARIF_3 = 
ACTIVE_ENERGY_PLUS_TARIF_4 = 
ACTIVE_ENERGY_MINUS_TOTAL =
```

Here's a link to a working [Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/1gXle1)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get a nice list of classes out the other end there's a bit of work to transform your almost-CSV style JSON to something that can be deserialized to a list of typed objects, e.g.:

```cs
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Newtonsoft.Json; // Install-Module Newtonsoft.JSON

namespace StackOverflow
{
    public class PowerReading
    {
        [JsonProperty("TERMINAL_NO")]
        public string TerminalNumber { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("METER_NO")]
        public string MeterNumber { get; set; }
        public string RAMZE_RAYANEH_SHENASE_GHABZ { get; set; }
        public string PARVANDEH_ESHTERAK { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("POWER_UTILITY")]
        public string PowerUtility { get; set; }
        public string CT_RATIO { get; set; }
        public string PT_RATIO { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("NAME_")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Part { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("CUSTOMER_ID")]
        public string CustomerId { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("X_POS")]
        public string XPos { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("Y_POS")]
        public string YPos { get; set; }
        public string DATE_NUM { get; set; }
        public string HOUR_NUM { get; set; }
        public string MONTH_ { get; set; }
        public string DAY_ { get; set; }
        public string YEAR_ { get; set; }
        public string DAY_WEEK { get; set; }
        public string DATE_HOUR { get; set; }
        public string ACTIVE_ENERGY_PLUS_TOTAL { get; set; }
        public string ACTIVE_ENERGY_PLUS_TARRIF1 { get; set; }
        public string ACTIVE_ENERGY_PLUS_TARRIF2 { get; set; }
        public string ACTIVE_ENERGY_PLUS_TARRIF3 { get; set; }
        public string ACTIVE_ENERGY_PLUS_TARRIF4 { get; set; }
        public string ACTIVE_ENERGY_MINUS_TOTAL { get; set; }
        public string ACTIVE_ENERGY_MINUS_TARRIF1 { get; set; }
        public string ACTIVE_ENERGY_MINUS_TARRIF2 { get; set; }
        public string ACTIVE_ENERGY_MINUS_TARRIF3 { get; set; }
        public string ACTIVE_ENERGY_MINUS_TARRIF4 { get; set; }
        public string REACTIVE_ENERGY_PLUS_TOTAL { get; set; }
        public string REACTIVE_ENERGY_PLUS_TARRIF1 { get; set; }
        public string REACTIVE_ENERGY_PLUS_TARRIF2 { get; set; }
        public string REACTIVE_ENERGY_PLUS_TARRIF3 { get; set; }
        public string REACTIVE_ENERGY_PLUS_TARRIF4 { get; set; }
        public string REACTIVE_ENERGY_MINUS_TOTAL { get; set; }
        public string REACTIVE_ENERGY_MINUS_TARRIF1 { get; set; }
        public string REACTIVE_ENERGY_MINUS_TARRIF2 { get; set; }
        public string REACTIVE_ENERGY_MINUS_TARRIF3 { get; set; }
        public string REACTIVE_ENERGY_MINUS_TARRIF4 { get; set; }
        public string VOLTAGE_PHASE_A { get; set; }
        public string VOLTAGE_PHASE_B { get; set; }
        public string VOLTAGE_PHASE_C { get; set; }
        public string CURRENT_PHASE_A { get; set; }
        public string CURRENT_PHASE_B { get; set; }
        public string CURRENT_PHASE_C { get; set; }
        public string POWER_ACTIV_AVG { get; set; }
        public string POWER_ACTIV_MIN { get; set; }
        public string POWER_ACTIV_MAX { get; set; }
        public string POWER_REACT_AVG { get; set; }
        public string POWER_REACT_MIN { get; set; }
        public string POWER_REACT_MAX { get; set; }
        public string POWER_FACTOR_PHASE_A { get; set; }
        public string POWER_FACTOR_PHASE_B { get; set; }
        public string POWER_FACTOR_PHASE_C { get; set; }
        public string READ_FLAG { get; set; }
    }

    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //First JSON pass: fix the JSON up enough to read in as an array of string arrays.
            var badJson = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("web_service.json");
            var arrayOfStringArrays = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string[][]>("[" + badJson + "]");

            //Use the first row as column headings (aka Object Property Names).
            var headings = arrayOfStringArrays.Take(1).FirstOrDefault();

            //Convert the remaining rows to a List of Dictionary<string,string> objects.
            var data = arrayOfStringArrays
                .Skip(1)
                .Select(row =>
                {
                    var colIndex = 0;
                    var dictionary = new System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, string>();
                    row.ToList().ForEach(col => dictionary.Add(headings[colIndex++], col));
                    return dictionary;
                });

            //Serialize the List<Dictionary<string,string>> back to JSON.
            var goodJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);

            //Now we can deserialize the JSON to list of typed objects.
            var powerReadings = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IList<PowerReading>>(goodJson);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The JSON is like a 2D array, except it is missing the start and ends of the outer array. You could restore them, and then parse as a 2D string array:

```
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string[][]>(jsonMessage);
```